# Python - drop elements from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame where are few columns.
I have also list of unique elements (elements from one of the columns).

I would like to leave only rows with elements in DataFrame which are included in my list.
I tried to do that but all my ideas failed.

Below quick example:

list = ["a", "b"]

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    a     ok
2    b     nok
3    c     ok
4    d     ok
5    a     nok
```

So I want to keep only rows where are A and B (elements from my list).

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df[column_you_want].isin(your_list)]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
df = df.loc[df["Col2"].isin(["a", "b"])]
```

will give:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3
1    a     ok
2    b     nok
5    a     nok
```

Comment: The resulting `df` will be a view, so mutating the `df` can give trouble down the line.
You should use `df.loc` instead, so that the return type is a real `DataFrame` rather than a view.